# rosserial_arduino failed to generate libraries for packages

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following the tutorials for rosserial_arduino and when I run

```
rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py
```

I get the error:

```
*** Warning, failed to generate libraries for the following packages: ***
map_msgs
relative_nav_msgs
```

I don't care about the map_msgs, but the relative_nav_msgs are custom message types that I need.

It looks like it breaks part way through the messages, this is the exact formatted output

```
Exporting relative_nav_msgs
Messages:
  Path,FilterState,Waypoint,Snapshot,Goal,DesiredVector,NodeInfo,Keyframe,Voltage,DEBUG_Controller,PartialState,Exporting turtle_actionlib
```

So it looks like something bad happened after the PartialState message and it skipped to Exporting the turtle_action lib.

Also, is there a way to turn off which types are built? For example, I don't actually care about the map_msgs, can I omit them from ros_lib?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200697/rosserial_arduino-failed-to-generate-libraries-for-packages/) by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-01-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-01-10**:
Did you already try [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/196222/rosserial-fails-to-generate-rosserial_msgs-library/)?

**Comment by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) on 2015-01-12**:
Yes, I have tried that but then it doesn't include my custom messages directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turns out the messages it cannot create headers for are the custom messages that are made of custom messages. My work around is to delete all of those types of messages and only create headers for the message I am interested in, which is made of floats. I will ask this question in a new thread.

---

Originally posted by [pnyholm](https://answers.ros.org/users/5202/pnyholm/) with karma: 97 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0